# Chef-InSpec: Resources for windows OS

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, inspec

I'm just starting to learn Inspec. I'm wondering to know is there any resources for check installed the driver(e.x virtio-win) or kernel in windows?

or is that possible to looking in one directory and say that test.sys exists?

Answer (score 0):

Check [the docs](http://inspec.io/docs/reference/resources/). What you see is what you get. I have no idea how to query a running a Windows kernel for which modules are loaded but if you know how to do that you can probably use a `command` resource. Otherwise just check for files like normal.

Answer (score 0):

I found that there are no resources for windows kernel. So, I just used `driverquery` to check the drivers.